# How to get selected item value

Tags: angularjs, selecteditem

i create list in my  HTML page:

```
 <label class="item item-input">
 <span class="input-label">Select date</span>
 <select  ng-model="search.dateOption" ng-options="opt as opt.label for opt in options">
 </select>
 </label>
```

In my controller  i define options:

```
$scope.options = [
  { label: 'Today'},
  { label: 'This week'},
  {  label: 'This month'},
  { label:'Other'}
]
```

I use the following function to get the selected item :

```
 $scope.selectedDate = function(){
 $scope.search={}
 console.log($scope.search )
 }
```

I get `undefined` in my console.

Answer (score 1):

try like this.

```js
var editer = angular.module('editer', []);
function myCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.options = [
  { label: 'Today'},
  { label: 'This week'},
  {  label: 'This month'},
  { label:'Other'}
];
  
  $scope.selectedDate = function(){
     console.log($scope.search )
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="editer" ng-controller="myCtrl" class="container">

<label class="item item-input">
 <span class="input-label">Select date</span>
 <select  ng-model="search.dateOption" ng-options="opt as opt.label for opt in options" ng-change="selectedDate()">
 </select>
 </label>
  
  <pre>{{search | json}}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It works here but in my project doesn"t work. May be coz of  my angularjs version . Am using 1.5.5

Comment: No. what display in console??

Comment: no thing is displayed in console just `undefined` . But    `<pre>{{search | json}}</pre>`  is working well.

Comment: please double check your code. all things is correct.

Comment: yeaah i check it very well . I copy and paste your code but i get undefined in console :\\

Answer (score 1):

**Its better to have an id for your dropdown list objects**

```js
var editer = angular.module('editer', []);

function myCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.dateOption = null;
  $scope.options = [{
    id: 1,
    label: 'Today'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    label: 'This week'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    label: 'This month'
  }, {
    id: 4,
    label: 'Other'
  }];

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="editer" ng-controller="myCtrl" class="container">

  <label class="item item-input">
    <span class="input-label">Select date</span>
    <select ng-model="dateOption" ng-options="opt as opt.label for opt in options">
    </select>
  </label>

  <pre>{{dateOption}}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: thank your for your response. But how i get  the value of dateOption from my controller ?

Comment: u can set $scope.dateOption = null;